# How can I restrict various roles with limit in creating nodes of a particular content type

Tags: 7, nodes, users

How can I restrict various roles with limit in creating nodes of a particular content type?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [node limit module](https://drupal.org/project/node_limit) to restrict nodes for various roles.

For `each roles` you can `create` a `node limit condition` with `certain limit` for `nodes` for tat `particular content type`.

[image]